# Loading On Demand - Once And Done For All in Grid

Tags: .net, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-combobox

I have a radgrid, which has 25 records displayed.  In the grid is a GridTemplateColumn with a RadComboBox in it.  The combo box has enabled loading on demand.  What I'd like to do is when one combo box loads, load them all.  I don't know if something like that is possible?  It's the same data for all.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can only be done by calling a JavaScript method on the API (_requestItems), and this has to be called one per.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that what GridDropDownColumn with LOD combo switched on do? It should load all items first and then get them from the cache when other combo editors are triggered. I stand corrected, though.

Comment: I'm using a GridTemplateColumn.  GridDropDownColumn does not show drop down for all rows, but only the one being edited.